# Why global and local namespaces are always the same in interactive session

Tags: python

Running `locals()` and `globals()` inside IDLE returns the same keys/values

I am extracting keys only with .`keys()` and convert to list using `list()`

```
['__doc__', '__spec__', '__builtins__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

Running the following code

```
z = 100
def f(x):
    y = 100
    return y
f(z)
```

Checking locals and globals again, all have the same keys/values

```
['z', '__doc__', '__spec__', '__builtins__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', 'f']
```

Why this is happening and why is variable `y` and `x` not showing up

Comment: `locals()` inside `f` don't show up in the interactive session.  `locals` only makes sense with checked or printed from within `f`.

Answer (score 1):

The variables that are defined inside the function do not exist any more after the function returned.

This is what allows you to have several functions with same internal variable names without interferences.

If you call `locals()` after the function call, `x` and `y` will therefore not appear.